# Dynamic flex + flexWrap won't work

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I have two questions:

1. Why doesn't my flexWrap work? My text doesn't wrap to start a new line when text length exceeds parent.
2. I really don't want to set a flex value of 1.5 to alertCardItem, I want the flex to adjust to the length of the warning message. How can I achieve this? I have tried setting flex to 0, doesn't work though

See image here [image]

I tried this using npm package react-native-easy-grid:

```
 <CardItem style={{borderBottomLeftRadius: 10, borderBottomRightRadius: 10, backgroundColor: '#fff'}}>
  <Grid>
     <Col>
       <Image style={styles.warning} source={Images.warning} />
     </Col>
     <Col size={3}>
         <Row><Text style={{flex: 1}}>Activity Alert</Text></Row>
         <Row><Text style={{flex: 1, flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>No activity on easy chair for 1 hour or soooo</Text></Row>
      </Col>
   </Grid>
 </CardItem>
```

I've also tried this with just using Views:

```
<CardItem style={{borderBottomLeftRadius: 10, borderBottomRightRadius: 10, backgroundColor: '#fff'}}>
  <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <Image style={styles.warning} source={Images.warning} />
  </View>
  <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'flex-start', justifyContent: 'flex-start'}}>
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'column', margin: 10, flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
      <Text style={{flex: 1}}>Activity Alert</Text>
      <Text style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>No activity on easy chair for 1 hour or soooo</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
 </View>
</CardItem>
```

Both codes yield the same results. 
 is a component from native base

The carditem is wrapped in component container and card with the following css:

```
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Metrics.titlePadding
  },

  card: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderColor: 'transparent',
    height: 250
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `View` container with `Text` components isn't restricted by width at all, so it extends as much as it needs to because of this very parent `View` (in particular its flex parameters). Try this:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'flex-start', justifyContent: 'flex-start'}}>
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'column', flex: 1, margin: 10}}>
        <Text style={{flex: 1}}>Activity Alert</Text>
        <Text style={{flex: 1}}>No activity on easy chair for 1 hour or soooo</Text>
    </View>
</View>
```

And you don't use `flexWrap` for this purpose. `flexWrap` defines whether the **flex items** will be forced to stay in a single line or move to the next one, not its content. If you want to control content wrapping use 'white-space' css property. It probably has its respesentation in React, but I am not very good at React tbh.

As for your second question it really hard to answer as I don't really know what happens beyond you `Card`. But if you want it to adjust itself to its content, flexbox is not the right tool.